# Docker Environment Variable Not Overridden

Tags: docker, environment-variables

Given I have a dockerfile like:

```
ARG MAX_MEMORY_PER_NODE="10GB"
ENV P_MAX_MEMORY_PER_NODE="${MAX_MEMORY_PER_NODE}"
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/p/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And the entrypoint.sh does something like:

```
echo "Max memory ${P_MAX_MEMORY_PER_NODE}"
```

If I were to run the container using the defaults, I would expect

```
Max Memory 10GB
```

And that works, but if I run

```
docker run me/mycontainer:latest -e P_MAX_MEMORY_PER_NODE=1GB
```

The script still uses the default value (does not print 1GB instead). In fact if I ran:

```
docker run me/mycontainer:latest -e A_TEST=Hello
```

And the script had

```
echo "My test: ${A_TEST}"
```

It would output

```
My test:
```

What am I doing wrong here? What can't I override (or even set) the environment variables being used in the entrypoint script from docker run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the environment variable before the image:

> docker run -e "A_TEST=hello" alpine env

Comment: Wow, this may be one of the dumber things I've done in awhile. Guess it would help if I followed the documentation on parameter order. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## For `docker-compose`

Similar to the this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48915478/11406645

when using `docker-compose`, and you are passing **docker-compose.yaml** file an environment variable, or overriding one in `env_file`; you should pass your environment variable like so: `DEBUG=1 docker-compose up`

### Another problem I faced is that docker commands require `sudo` permissions:

If you are using `sudo` before the `docker-compose` command, add the environment variable after the `sudo` like so: `sudo DEBUG=1 docker-compose up`.

### The wrong way:

`DEBUG=1 sudo docker-compose up`

### The right way:

`sudo DEBUG=1 docker-compose up`